# C++ console - Formatting output

Tags: c++, format, output

I have a `nxn` grid of randomly generated numbers. I have a label that displays the element numbers for the X and Y axis:

[image]

It aligns up properly for single digit numbers, but when the grid size increases the labels become out of proportion and don't line up like so:

[image]

I'm wondering if there is any way to make the label line up with the numbers within the grid and scales depending on the size. Is this even possible?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Will the random numbers always be one digit?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to determine the number of digits in an integer:

```
int getDigits(int col)
{
    int len = 1;
    while ( col/= 10 )
    {
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}
```

With this you can determine the number of `" "` to print as you loop through.

```
std::string space(getDigits(column), ' ');
std::cout<<space<<num;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use two rows for the top numbering and work out a simple calculation to determine whether or not to display the digit for that row.
For instance, the top row could be for the 'tens' column and the second row for the units. You know you have 20 columns, so you could display a space character or zero if the current count of a loop is less than 10. If it's not less than 10, display a 1 character. 
The bottom row could then just cycle through 0 - 9 twice.